# Sequelize error handling

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

take a look at the example code below, I wonder if it is enough to just chain one `.catch()` on the outer most sequelize task instead of always chaining it on each task which looks quite messy.

The second question would be is it possible to make `.then(instance, error)` contain the error object if there is any? like in mongoose the 1st argument is always the err obj. So i don't have to `.catch` an error but simply handle it in the `.then()` callback fn.

```
function facebookStrategy() {
  return new FacebookStrategy({
    clientID: config.facebook.app_id,
    clientSecret: config.facebook.app_secret
  }, function (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
    process.nextTick(function () {
      models.User.findOrCreate({
        where: {email: profile.emails[0].value}
      }).spread(function (user, created) {
        models.UserPassport.findOrCreate({
          where: {
            // TODO(tsm): check out sequelize composite keys
            method: 'facebook',
            social_id: profile.id
          },
          defaults: {
            method: 'facebook',
            token: accessToken,
            social_id: profile.id
          }
        }).spread(function (userPassport, created) {
          userPassport.setUser(user).then(function () {
            user.updateAttributes({
              first_name: profile.name.givenName,
              last_name: profile.name.familyName
            }).then(function () {
              return done(null, user);
            });
          });
        }).catch(function (err) {
          console.log('Error occured: ', err);
          return done(err);
        });
      }).catch(function (err) {
        console.log('Error occured: ', err);
        return done(err);
      });
    })
  })
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By returning a promise you can chain it.

So you can do something like

```
function facebookStrategy() {
    return new FacebookStrategy({
        clientID: config.facebook.app_id,
        clientSecret: config.facebook.app_secret
    }, function (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
        process.nextTick(function () {
            models.User.findOrCreate({
                where: {
                    email: profile.emails[0].value
                }
            }).spread(function (user, created) {
                return models.UserPassport.findOrCreate({
                    where: {
                        // TODO(tsm): check out sequelize composite keys
                        method: 'facebook',
                        social_id: profile.id
                    },
                    defaults: {
                        method: 'facebook',
                        token: accessToken,
                        social_id: profile.id
                    }
                }).spread(function (userPassport, created) {
                    return userPassport.setUser(user).then(function () {
                        return user.updateAttributes({
                            first_name: profile.name.givenName,
                            last_name: profile.name.familyName
                        }).then(function () {
                            return done(null, user);
                        });
                    });
                });
            }).catch(done);
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: Cool, so basically all sequelize query methods can return a promise and the error will bubble down to the outer most one.